# TFS- how to get workitem data using java sdk

Tags: java

Can I get value of workitem fields, for example related to "Assigned to" field, from Workitem object? I use TFS SDK for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to view work items  of TFS using below code:

```
public static  TFSTeamProjectCollection connectToTFS() throws URIException, SQLException
{
    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = null;
    Credentials credentials;

    credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username,"password");
    tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI("http://0.0.0.127:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"), credentials);
    return tpc;
}


// get connection using above method
TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc=connectToTFS();
WorkItemClient workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient();
// Define the WIQL query.          
String wiqlQuery = "Select ID, Title from WorkItems where (State = 'Active') order by Title";

// Run the query and get the results.          
WorkItemCollection workItems = workItemClient.query(wiqlQuery); 
final int maxToPrint = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < workItems.size(); i++)          
{ 
    if (i >= maxToPrint)              
    { 
        System.out.println("[...]");                  
        break; 
    } 
    WorkItem workItem = workItems.getWorkItem(i); 

    System.out.println(workItem.getID());
    System.out.println(workItem.getTitle()); 
    System.out.println(workItem.getProject().getName()); 
    System.out.println(workItem.getClient().getUserDisplayName());        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below statements we can get exactly assign_to field value.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < workItems.size(); i++)          
    { 

        WorkItem workItem = workItems.getWorkItem(i);  

        workItem.syncToLatest();
            System.out.println("task  assigned to "+ workItem.getFields().getField("Assigned to").getValue()+" Task title is   "+workItem.getFields().getField("title").getOriginalValue());


    }
```